# finding highest correlation in my correlation matrix by writing a conditional for code

Tags: python, for-loop, correlation

I have a correlation matrix that is about the effect of some factors on rain in a specific area and now I want to write a conditional for loop that can extract the correlations that are greater than 0.6 and smaller than -0.7  and print me this message for example :
MaxTemp and Temp9am variables are strongly correlated (correlation coefficient = 0.89)
I write this code:

```
c1 = corelation.abs().unstack()
my_try=pd.DataFrame(data=c1)
for i in my_try:
    value=my_try[i>0.66]
    print('{values} is strongly positively correlated(correlation coefficient = {amount}'.format(amount=i , values=value))
```

but returns me this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-24d6b566ed34> in <module>
      1 for i in my_try:
----> 2     value=my_try[i>0.66]
      3     print('{values} is strongly positively correlated(correlation coefficient = {amount}'.format(amount=i , values=value))

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

now, how can I fix it ??
I will be glad to someone help me with this code

Answer (score 1):

try this custom function it may works. It extracts the features which are correlated over 0.3 (can be change) in absolute value (>0.3 and <-0.3)

```
def good_correlation(df1, treshold=0.3):
    cm = df1.corr() #correlation matrix
    np.fill_diagonal(cm.values, 0) # set diagonal to 0 
    corr = [(cm.index[x], cm.columns[y], cm.iloc[x,y]) for x, y in zip(*np.where(abs(np.tril(cm)) > treshold))] # create couple (feature1, feature2, value)
    for couple in corr:
        feature1, feature2, value = couple
        print(f'{feature1} and {feature2} are strongly correlated (treshold = {treshold}) (value = {value})')

    return cm, corr
```

it returns cm and corr if needed for next step. If you need to make two different tresholds you can add an argument in the def and change the condition in the list comprehension !
if you need more info on the function just ask.

Have a great day/afternoon/night :)

Comment: I add my next threshold and run it but it returns error :def good_correlation(df, treshold1=0.6 , treshold2=-0.6):
    cm = df.corr() #correlation matrix
    np.fill_diagonal(cm.values, 0) # set diagonal to 0 
    corr = [(cm.index[x], cm.columns[y], cm.iloc[x,y]) for x, y in zip(*np.where(abs(np.tril(cm)) > treshold1 & abs(np.tril(cm)) < treshold2 ))] # create couple (feature1, feature2, value)
    for couple in corr:
        feature1, feature2, value = couple
        print(f'{feature1} and {feature2} are strongly correlated (treshold = {treshold}) (value = {value})')

Comment: try with this:
` def good_correlation(df1, neg_treshold=-0.2, pos_treshold=0.3):
    cm = df1.corr()
    np.fill_diagonal(cm.values, 0)
    corr = [(cm.index[x], cm.columns[y], cm.iloc[x,y]) for x, y in zip(*np.where((np.tril(cm) > pos_treshold) + (np.tril(cm) < neg_treshold)))]
    for couple in corr:
        feature1, feature2, value = couple
        print(f'{feature1} and {feature2} are strongly correlated (neg_treshold = {neg_treshold} / pos_treshold = {pos_treshold}) (value = {value})')

    return cm, corr

here, it will extract [-1:-0.2[ and ]0,3:1].